# $2/3$ of a tank contains $112$ litres of water. What will it contain when it is $3/4$ full?

Tags: fractions

$2/3$ of a tank contains $112$ litres of water. What will it contain when it is $3/4$ full?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If the tank holds $x$ liters in total, then 
$$\frac{2}{3}x=112$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\frac 34 T= \frac 34 \cdot \frac32\cdot\left( \frac 23 T\right)$